# Joining the same table based on recent Timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I need to get a view which will have the entry for each `sername` based on the recent execution time on that `sername`. Below is the table mock data and expected view.

Table data:

| id | sername | status | program | exectime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ser1 | running | ext1 | 2017-11-29 10:00:00 |
| 2 | ser1 | abended | ext1 | 2017-11-29 10:00:00 |
| 3 | ser1 | running | ext1 | 2017-11-29 10:00:00 |
| 4 | ser1 | running | ext1 | 2017-11-27 10:00:00 |
| 5 | ser1 | running | ext1 | 2017-11-27 10:00:00 |
| 6 | ser2 | running | ext1 | 2017-11-29 10:15:00 |
| 7 | ser2 | stopped | ext1 | 2017-11-29 10:15:00 |
| 8 | ser2 | running | ext1 | 2017-11-28 10:15:00 |
| 9 | ser2 | running | ext1 | 2017-11-28 10:15:00 |
| 10 | ser2 | running | ext1 | 2017-11-28 10:15:00 |

Expected result:

```
|2  |ser1   |abended    |2017-11-29 10:00:00|
|7  |ser2   |stopped    |2017-11-29 10:15:00|
```

I have tried below query but it doesn't include the recent time for the particular server.

```sql
select DISTINCT sername, max(id) as id, (select max(status) from orastatus g2 
            where g1.sername=g2.sername group by g2.sername) 
            as gstatus, max(exectime) from orastatus g1 group by sername
```

Comment: in sername you have identical exectime `2017-11-29 10:00:00` then how to decide which one we need to choose. is there any logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `DISTINCT ON`.

As per your expected output you have a lower preference of `running` status in compare to  `stopped` and `abended` status. so there are 2 scenario if we need to ignore the status then it is simply like below:

```
select distinct on (sername) id,sername,status,exectime from orastatus order by sername, exectime desc
```

But in case you want to consider the status then

```
with cte as (
select 'running' "status", 1  "value"
union all 
select 'abended',2
union all
select 'stopped',3
)
select 
distinct on (sername) t1.id, t1.sername, t1.status, t1.exectime 
from 
orastatus t1 
inner join cte on t1.status=cte.status 
order by sername, exectime desc, cte.value desc
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e50cea04f3db23dc0b4cf393b15fdf63)

Comment: This is returning fine but what if the table has few other columns as well. Instead of all the columns, can we get only the desired columns - id, sername, exectime, status

Comment: yes, instead of `*`, use `select distinct on (sername)  id, sername, ........ from`. updated the answer

Comment: Also, can we use something else instead of double quotes on "status", 1  "value". I am using the query in spring xml, and this is causing issue

Comment: its upto you. you can use anything but same you have to updatein join also

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (not tested)

```
select g1.* 
from orastatus g1,
(select sername, max(id) as id group by sername) g2
where g1.id = g2.id
```